# Compilation error when using Media9 package

Tags: beamer, media9, music

I am compiling this example from [example link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89916/how-to-play-background-music-across-multiple-slides-when-making-a-beamer-present)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{dumb frame}
\dots
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{frame with sound \includemedia[
  label=my_sound,
  width=1ex, height=1ex, transparent,
  activate=pageopen, deactivate=onclick,
  addresource=sound_sample.mp3,
  flashvars={
    source=sound_sample.mp3
   &autoPlay=true
   &hideBar=true
  },
]{}{APlayer.swf}}
\dots
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{other frame}
\dots
\end{frame}

\pdfpageattr{/AA <</O <</S/JavaScript/JS (annotRM['my_sound'].activated=false;)>> >>}
\begin{frame}{frame where sound stops}
\dots
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{another dumb frame}
\dots
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am using Win7 64bit, Miktex 2.9 TeXworks with pdfLaTex compilation. I keep getting this error

> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
>   2.9\tex\latex\beamer\translator\dicts\translator-theo rem-dictionary\translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict") No file
>   embed_mp3.nav.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not
>   available (Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 8.
>
> [1{C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
>   ! Undefined control sequence.  \file_get_full_name:nN 
>                                     {APlayer.swf}\l_mix_file_tl
>
> l.22 \end{frame}

The log file is saved [here](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/q6BCDAF1) (as it exceeded the word limit in the question)

I can successfully embed wav file using  package multimedia using code

```
\begin{center}
\movie[label=show,
start=0s,height = 0cm,width = 6cm, showcontrols]{}{media/specific-information-1-of-3.wav} 
\end{center}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{center}
\hyperlinkmovie[play]{show}{\beamerbutton{play}}
\hyperlinkmovie[pause]{show}{\beamerbutton{pause}}
\hyperlinkmovie[resume]{show}{\beamerbutton{resume}}
\hyperlinkmovie[stop]{show}{\beamerbutton{stop}}
\end{center}
```

But package Media9 never worked and it kept showing the above error message.
Thank you.

Comment: I can compile your file but obviously I do not have the mp3 file.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely have the mp3 file in the right folder. That's why I am puzzled as it seems no one asked this question before.

Comment: Compiles also fine for me (replacing the mp3 with a dummy one I had lying around). A few wild guesses to check: Can you test to rename your file to `soundsample.mp3` (without special characters like `_`)? Can you test to embeded the sound outside the frametitle and instead try in the body of the frame? Which version of beamer do you have?

Comment: Put `\listfiles` at the top of your tex input file. And post the file list here. It can be found in the `*.log` file after running `pdflatex`.

Comment: @samcarter Tried both and neither worked. beamer 3.41

Comment: @shj37 That's pretty old beamer version, can you update (maybe even your complete tex distribution, but especially all expl3 related components)?

Comment: @samcarter Thanks. Just updated beamer to the latest version, still have the same error message. I will try to update them all, but it gonna take a while

Comment: @shj37 After you updated all the other packages, make sure to also remove all the auxiliary files before you compile again.

Comment: @shj37 Many of your packages are not up to date. For example the etoolbox package is 1.5 years behind the current version.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I am not misusing the space for further question again.
It is working now. I updated the following packages (though I am sure different settings should require updating different packages)

```
l3kernel
beamer
media9
l3packages
etoolbox
```

Thanks, @samcarter @AlexG @Phelype Oleinik and everyone else offerred suggestions. I learned a lot through the process.

Comment: Good to see an answer in this space :)